# Remove p tags from around object tags in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a way to remove p tags from around object tags in WordPress. I have already found a way to remove the p tags from around img and iframe tags, but would like to extend the following code to include the object tag.

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
  $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
  return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just copy the iframe part?

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<object.*>*.<\/object>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Answer (score -1):

Put in your theme's function.php file the line:

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```